# How to properly declare volumes in HelmV3?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm currently working to modify Helm charts from Helm V2 to Helm V3 and I have many compatibility errors.

I have such declaration of configmap :

```
  ConfigMap:
      data.properties: |
        data1: my_data
        data2: my beautiful_data
        data3: my wonderful_data
      config.properties: |
        config1: my_config
        config2: my_beautiful_config
        config3: my_wonderful_config
```

And until now I declared my volumes like that :

```
  volumes:
      - name: configmap-config
        configMap:
          name: "config-configmap"
          key: config.properties
          path: config.properties
      - name: configmap-data
        configMap:
          name: "data-configmap"
          key: data.properties
          path: data.properties
```

But with Helm V3 I get this error :

```
[ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].configMap): unknown field \"key\" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMapVolumeSource,
ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].configMap): unknown field \"path\" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMapVolumeSource,
```

I've made several searches but I didn't found a documentation explaining the differences between charts in V2 and charts in V3. How volumes have to be declared in Helm V3 with this configmap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an issue with helm version.I guess it's something to do with your kubernetes yaml file.
The correct way to mount a configmap using volumes

```
 volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: example-redis-config
        items:
        - key: redis-config
          path: redis.conf
```

I am not sure why it will work with helm v2 but try updating your yaml file

Comment: I am slowly learning and still confusing between Helm and kubectl parts.
Thank you !